# Increment an SQL table key in one for stored data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build an script for a database migration and I have a doubt. I have a table which has lots of registers and an integer type key. This key is auto incremental and now beginning with the '1' index.

The problem is that this index has to be occupied by a default value in the new database. So I want to loop database rows to get each index incremented in one, to leave the first place in blank and insert my value into it. I have tried with this statement:

```
UPDATE `tapp`, (
  SELECT @loop := id_App
  FROM
    tapp
  ) o
SET id_App = id_App + 1;
```

However, is trying to update each index starting from the beginning, so when it tries converting the first one to '2' it finds out the second one is already taken and can't make it.

It's important to make the increase in one, because it's a MyIsam database and I also have to update each foreign key one by one. I'm using MySQL.

Please give me a hand!

Comment: You can specify an `ORDER BY` clause to `UPDATE`... but it sounds as though you're going about this all the wrong way.

Comment: Tried with ORDER BY id_App DESC, does not work. It's trying to create duplicate entries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is twofold: After inserting everything into the target table, you make a 2-pass update.

First, you check what the highest number is in the table, then increment it by one and remember it as topnumber.

Then, you update everything to incremental numbers, starting with topnumber. Finally, you update everything, starting with whatever your initial seed is and increment by one each record.

```
number data
1      "foo"
3      "bar"
10     "snafu"
```

topnumber becomes 11

After the first pass, the data looks like this:

```
number data
11     "foo"
12     "bar"
13     "snafu"
```

After the second pass (and assuming your initial number is 7), the data looks like this:

```
number data
7      "foo"
8      "bar"
9      "snafu"
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, instead of updating the numbers to incremental values, you could add the remembered top number to every initial value at the first pass (and so the above sample table would look like this after the first update:

```
number data
11     "foo"
13     "bar"
23     "snafu"
```

), and at the second pass, you would decrement all the numbers by the previously stored top number and increment them by 1, which, for our example, would result in the following:

```
number data
2      "foo"
4      "bar"
11     "snafu"
```

Using the names in your code snippet, the entire script might look something like this:

```
/* remember the top ID */
SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tapp);

/* increment by the top ID */
UPDATE tapp SET id_App = id_App + @max_id;

/* decrement by the top ID and increment by 1 */
UPDATE tapp SET id_App = id_App - @max_id + 1;
```

Comment: My idea is to increment each index in one, so from the numbers you're initially giving, the final result should be 2,4 and 11.
 
I'm dealing with MyISAM tables and I have no relations established into the database, so once I update the main one I must also update the FKs of the dependent tables manually. So I need a fixed increment of each index...

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Store the maximum `id_App` in a variable, add that value to every `id_App` at the first pass, subtract that value and add 1 at the second pass. If your last `id_App` is less then half the maximum possible value for the data type, you should be fine.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: If `id_App` is a signed integer type (int or bigint) and you do not use negatives, then it should be even easier: `SET id_App = -id_App` at the first pass, `SET id_App = -id_App + 1` at the second one.

Comment: Is there a way to store a variable like that in SQL script and use it in a loop?

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Not sure what you mean by loop, but in an UPDATE statement, yes, you could use a variable. I'm talking about something like this: `SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tapp); UPDATE tapp SET id_App = id_App + @max_id; UPDATE tapp SET id_App = id_App - @max_id + 1;`.

Comment: @Andriy M Good choice! Can you put your solution in a separate answer for me to mark it as the good one?

Comment: @XtremeBiker: The basic idea of using two passes and remembering the top ID belongs to 0xCAFEBABE. I've updated their answer so that you can accept it.